# How to remove mouse cursor in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I recently started using Vimium to not use the mouse that often. Now I find it disturbing when I always see the mouse cursor within Chrome.

So I want it to disappear from screen when I am not using the mouse. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried [requesting the feature](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb/reviews) from the [devs](http://vimium.github.com/)? The should be able to add a function-call to remove it, but you will need to allow that to happen since by default, Chrome prompts you: `chrome://chrome/settings/contentExceptions#mouselock`

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to override the user stylesheet.
You can use an extension like [UserScrtipCSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdfbjinabdohnegjnbfgdgohlhegamnm)
and set a rule of 
`body { cursor: none !important; }` to match against a regex of `.*`.

This will obviously remove the mouse cursor completely from every page - which may or may not be what you want.